# Перестала работать сеть в виртуальном Debian в VWWare под управлением хоста Win10

Tags: сеть, windows-10, vmware

Была обычная установка VMWare Player и подключение ПК по кабелю, в настройках сети виртуальной машины было выбрано Bridged и под ним был отмечен чекбокс "Replicate physical network connection state" - всё работало, виртуалка получала адрес в подсети хоста.

После переезда подключить по проводу ПК не представляется возможным на новом месте - комп подключен по WiFi. Виртуалка перестала получать адрес в сети хоста и вообще не видит сеть в режиме Bridged. В других режимах получает левые алреса, на которые не пробиться если там запустить например слушающий сокет. Переустанавливал плеер - без результата.

Как вернуть виртуалку в подсеть хоста, как настроить этот мост?